# How can I get an Object's name in java?

Tags: java

like this, A a = new A(), how can I get a's name?(Get a String "a" from a) ?

---

There is a JPanel contains some JTextFields, a map contains all the JTextFields' names(the variables' names). I want to set the map's values to the JTextFields' texts.

```
public void mapToJPanel(Map map, JPanel panel) {
    Component[] compArr = panel.getComponents();
    for (Component comp : compArr) {
        if (comp.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("JTextField")) {
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) comp;
            textField.setText(map.get(textField.getName()).toString());//getName() method
        }
    }
}
```

Accross getName() method, I get null -_- I know the getName() method is not used to get the variable name.
I'm using netbeans doing Java swing visual development , so I can not  rewrite the components(like JTextField).

Comment: can you explain a little in what scenario this would be useful?  Suppose you have `A a = new A();`, what would you expect to be returned after you do `A b = a;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Component.setName()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName(java.lang.String)) to give names to Swing and AWT components.

Comment: Maybe this is the best solution :)

Answer (score 17):

You cannot, because an object does not have a name.  Consider the following for example:

```
A a = new A();
A b = a;
```

What is the "name" of the `A` instance now?  Is it `"a"`?  Is it `"b"`?

And what about this?

```
A[] a = new A[] { new A(), new A()};
a[0] = a[1];
```

What is the "name" of the instance at `a[1]`?

My point is that you cannot come up with a useful / usable definition of a universal Java object name that works in a wide range of contexts.  Roadblock issues include:

- Name stability: a "name" that changes when an object's reference is assigned is not useful.
- Single name: an object should not simultaneously have multiple names.
- Implementability: any naming system would have to be implementable without imposing a performance cost on normal usage of objects.  AFAIK, this is impossible ... at least on the kind of hardware we currently use.

The closest that Java comes to a name for an object is the object's "identity hashcode" value.  It is not unique, but it has the property that it won't change for the lifetime of the object in the current JVM.  (But even the identity hashcode comes at a runtime cost ... which makes it a Java design mistake in some peoples' view.)

The sensible approach to naming objects is (as others have said) to add "name" fields to the relevant classes (or use an existing one) and manage the names yourself as required.

---

In the more specific case where the "object" is actually a `JComponent`, a given component cannot be relied on to have a name.  (The `getName()` method can return `null`.)  However, if you wanted to, you could traverse any `JComponent` hierarchy and set a name on any components as appropriate.

Comment: If "a" is not the name of an object, then how can you call it? Reference of an address on the memory reserved for an object?

Comment: It (`a`) is the identifier (or "name")  for a variable that contains a reference to the object.  It is not a "name" for an object because the reference in the variable can be changed.  A "name" for an object would not change just because I assigned it to a different variable.  Note - I am using "name" here in the same way that the person who wrote the original question did.

Comment: So, when you say 'reference', you mean address on the memory, right? That means, if I have many objects, then I will have a different address for each object. That means, I must use different identifiers/variables for each object. ´Stud a = new Stud("John"); Stud b = new Stud("Michael");´. Is it right?

Comment: Not necessarily.  `Stud[] studs = new Stud[]{new Stud("John"), new Stud("Fred")};`  Or `Stud a = new Stud("John"); a = new Stud("Fred");`

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

If you compile with debug symbols then the .class file will contain a table of variable names (which is how debuggers map variables back to your source code), but there's no guarantee this will be there and it's not exposed in the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can't and it seems like you're doing something wrong if you need to do this. However, if you really want to pursue the logic you've outlined, why don't you do the following:

Add a String member to A and in a constructor, assign it. Something like this:

```
 A a = new A('a');
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can easily get the name of a variable's class by invoking .getClass().getCanonicalName() or .getClass().getSimpleName() (depending on whether you want the fully qualified name), it is not so easy to get the name of a variable. Java bytecode does not need to preserve the names of local variables (which are represented using push/pop operations on the stack); however, Java bytecode may contain the original names in comments. So, you might try reading the .class files from the .jar files and attempt to extract the variable names from the .class files, assuming that the compiler has included them as comments. As for member variables (i.e. fields), you can use reflection to get a class's field names.

Comment: Note that getClass gives you the *object*'s class, not the variable's class (i.e. if you do `Object x = "hello"`, `x.getClass()` will be String, not Object). There is no way to get a local variable's class from the object the variable points to - just like there's no way to get the variable's name.

Comment: @sepp2k, the distinction you are trying to make between "object" and "variable" is, I believe, non-standard. When trying to make that distinction, one typically speaks of "run-time type" vs. "compile-time type" or of "run-time type" vs "declared type". I am using "variable" somewhat colloquially/loosely to mean the value denoted by the variable.

Comment: I don't whether it's a standard (though I do know I'm not the first person to make it), but I think it's important to understand that an object can be pointed to by more than one variable or by no variable at all, which makes concepts like an object's name meaningless. I believe the distinction makes that clear and is thus a useful one to make.

Comment: @sepp2k, yes, that is true, two different variables may denote the same underlying object.

Answer (score 0):

The replication of the name (symbol) a is what is inconvenient and a bit noisy.
In a language with macros, one could define this so that the copying would be automatic in the source code program.

```
make(A, a);
```

or
    makeA(a)

Answer (score 0):

You can always create name variable in the object's class, and use that variable beside others to pass information about this object.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, look that solution...

```
    DocumentoMB mb = new DocumentoMB();
    System.out.println(mb.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Comment: That gives the class name, not `mb`, the object reference name