# Get object name in Java

Tags: java

How can I get an object name? For example

```java
Objet o = new Object();
```

I want to get this "o" and print it.

Comment: Objects don't have names. This is important since a single object can be assigned to 100 variables, or to a collection or array, and when this happens, pray tell, *which one* is the "object's name"? Besides, variable names don't really matter much in compiled code and in fact *almost* don't even exist. It's all about references.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894127/how-can-i-get-an-objects-name-in-java

Comment: if the class in question has a tostring method defined for it, you can call that

Comment: If you're looking for the name of the variable, you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the name of the variable to print it.

Comment: mpluse -- this is not a good thing to do as per my comments above. I urge you to re-think why you think you even need this, and then report this need back to us.

Comment: Well, I'm working about a mini-project. They demand to display all cars driven by one given driver. I can print fields of cars but I look for an identifier for each car. I don't have any identifier on fields so I search for how to get this name of the variable.

Comment: Use a variable as an instance of your car object to identify each car. For example a string that works as an identifier for each of your car objects.

Comment: @AliAlamiri I didn't get it!

Comment: Check the answer I provided. Hope it's what you need.

Comment: @mpluse: thanks for giving more information. Next time you have a question, please give all the needed information from the get-go. This having to pull information out can get tiresome after a while, and you'll get much better help quicker if you do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have an identifier for an object that you create, you can simply have an instance of your object that holds the identifier of each object you create.

For example if you have a class called `Car`, then that class can have a `String` variable called id, which can be used with each Car object created to give that object an identifier. E.g.

```
class Car 
{
    private String id;

    public Car(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Then now when you create a Car object, you pass a unique identifier for that object to the constructor:

```
Car car1 = new Car("c1");
```

If you then want to get the id of each car, you get use a getter method that return the id field of a specific car object. For example:

```
public String getId()
{
   return id;
}
```

then you can get the id of car1 by doing this:

```
System.out.println(car1.getId());
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't have required reputations