# How to call the name of the object in Java?

Tags: java, object

I have created an object

`Student student1 = new Student(***, ***, ***, ***);`

In my toString override, how do I pull/reference the object's identifier student1? Without creating a field for it.

```
   @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
            "id=" + this.id +
            '}';
}

System.out.println(student1)
```

I want the output to be Student{student1, id=***}

Comment: Why do you want this? The variable name should have no effect on the execution of the code and also no relevance to the user of the software.

Comment: @jmizv because that is what I was told to do. If it is impossible fine, but I just want to do my due diligence, before I say it can't be done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get object name in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345159/get-object-name-in-java)

Comment: @Nora Na I was asked to do it without creating an instance/field.  Which I have been told is currently impossible and will probably remain so for security reasons. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects exist independently of any variables that reference them. You **can't** use their variable name in a `toString()` or any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a student object and call the `toString()` method on the student object.

For eg,

```
Student student1 = new Student(***, ***, ***, ***);  
student1.toString();
```

This will call your override method `toString()` in your Student class.

In your toString method on Student class, you don't need stdout or any output.

Just `return "Student { "id =" + this.id }";`