# Getting ImageButton Name

Tags: android, arraylist, get, imagebutton

I am having some trouble with my code, and I am trying to figure out where each ImageButton is in my ArrayList to see if the problem is there.  How do I retreive the name of an ImageButton from an ArrayList?

```
List<ImageButton> images = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();
images.add(imgbut1);
images.add(imgbut2);
images.add(imgbut3);
images.add(imgbut4);
images.add(imgbut5);
```

Here, I want to get `imgbut1` for `images.get(0)`, `imgbut2` for `images.get(1)`, etc.  Something like `images.get(0).getName()`, `images.get(1).getName()`, etc

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

imgbut1, imgbut2 are names you gave to your instances. You cannot get the name.

Here are some good examples
[Get name java instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894127/how-can-i-get-an-objects-name-in-java)

Comment: I added another thread, please accept the answer if you consider it good :)